# Get alll customer mobile phone numbers in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, phone-number, user-data

I want to loop all the phone numbers of my users into an input field. So far, I'm not getting any luck with the following:

```
<?php for get_user_meta('phone_number',true); { echo $phone; "," } ?>
```

I'm trying to list them as `07812345678, 07812345678, 07812345678,` etc... until the last number where there is no "," following it. Can someone help me? This is executed on the homepage of the admin dashboard if that makes any difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this custom shortcode that uses a very light sql query to get **all "customer"** user role **"billing phone" numbers** as a coma separated string of number phones

If you are using a custom phone number custom field, you just need to replace in the function `billing_phone` by your custom field slug *(as `phone_number` for example)*

```
add_shortcode( 'customers_phones', 'get_customers_phone' );
function get_customers_phone(){
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT um.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users as u
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta as um ON um.user_id = u.ID
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta as um2 ON um2.user_id = u.ID
        WHERE um.meta_key LIKE 'billing_phone' AND um.meta_value != ''
        AND um2.meta_key LIKE 'wp_capabilities' AND um2.meta_value NOT LIKE '%administrator%'
    " );

    // return a coma separated string of "customer" billing phones numbers
    return implode( ', ', $results );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE** - Displaying the number phones coma separated string:

1. In any Wordpress post or page text editor that accepts shortcodes:

   ```
   [customers_phones]
   ```
2. Inside php code

   ```
   echo do_shortcode("[customers_phones]");
   ```
3. Inside html code in a php file

   ```
   <?php echo do_shortcode("[customers_phones]"); ?>
   ```

---

Here below a replacement version without targeting "customer" user role:

```
add_shortcode( 'customers_phones', 'get_customers_phone' );
function get_customers_phone(){
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT um.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users as u
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta as um ON um.user_id = u.ID
        WHERE um.meta_key LIKE 'billing_phone' AND um.meta_value != ''
    " );

    // return a coma separated string of "customer" billing phones numbers
    return implode( ', ', $results ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this and it doesn't output anything? Perhaps the meta has a different name?

Comment: No, billing_phone is correct... I don't know why it isn't working. I did everything as above?

Comment: Yep just tried it. It's trying to do something as the shortcode disappears and doesn't show, but it doesn't output anything either... :(

Comment: Maybe try it for the "Subscriber" role instead of "Customer" role? How do I change this?

Comment: @NathanWinch Look this is the shortcode on my test server on a specific page (I have only few customers): https://www.cbleu.net/sites/wc34/my-wardrobe/

Comment: I have WooCommerce Subscriptions

Answer (score 2):

If your input data is already in an array then you can just use `implode()`. This will join all the items of the array with the indicated separator.

```
echo implode(', ', get_user_meta('phone_number',true));
```

Comment: I'm not sure they are in an array?

Comment: How do I do that? :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked long a while ago, but I will post what was useful to me.

To select all phone numbers saved as billing phones from Woocommerce's checkout form you can use a function like this:

```
/**
 * Get billing phone numbers, join them by a comma and return them as a string.
 */
function customer_loyalty_with_twilio_get_customers_phone(){
    global $wpdb;

    // use $wpdb to make a query directly to the database
    $results = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT DISTINCT `meta_value` FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'billing_phone' and `meta_value` != '';
    ");

    // return a coma separated string of "customer" billing phones numbers
    return implode( ',', $results );
}
```

The way this works is by using the database access abstraction class, `$wpdb`. The SQL query is selecting all DISTINCT `meta_value`'s from the table {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta (if your tables are prefixed by "wp_", then the table will be called `wp_postmeta`). The query filters results where `meta_key` column is equal to "_billing_phone". I added the last condition, `` and `meta_value` != '' ``, to exclude empty records.

Hope this is useful to somebody.